# difference between 'deliberately' and 'on purpose'

Tags: difference

Please read the following sentences.

1. He deliberately did that.
2. He did that on purpose.

What's the difference ?

Could you give me any more examples which will clarify where to use these words ?

Comment: Note that you can say "He did that **deliberately**" but not ＊"He **on purpose** did that".

Comment: They mean the same in this context. You can also say "He didn't do that on purpose".  He did it, but not on purpose.

Answer (score 5):

*Deliberately* and *on purpose* can be used interchangeably to mean "intentionally".

But *deliberate* (adj) and *deliberately* (adv) also mean "done with care, methodically."

**He made the sandwich very deliberately, carefully covering the bread with a layer of peanut butter and then evenly applying the jelly.**

Comment: Isn't "carefully" redundant if you have "deliberately" before it?

Comment: What do you mean by "redundant"?

Comment: @Andy, carefully is not redundant. Deliberately modifies "made" and carefully modifies "covering"

Comment: @eques That's being a bit pedantic; remove either of those words from the sentence and its meaning would remain unchanged.

Comment: Deliberately might mean in a particular order or manner, e.g. peanut butter on one piece of bread, jelly on the other, and carefully could mean taking care to keep the layers even and not too close to the edge of the bread.  The words do not have identical meanings.

Comment: It's not pedantic. That's how English works. "He made the sandwich, carefully covering the bread..." is a valid sentence, but of course without "very deliberately" it needs context to make sense with "the". "He made the sandwich very deliberately, covering the bread with a layer..." is also valid. Both sentences mean something similar to the original, but with different emphases. Using only carefully would describe only the manner of applying peanut butter versus describing the overall sandwich making.

Comment: Making a sandwich deliberately might imply covering carefully, but they are not identical in meaning. That's the point of language flexibility; various shades of meaning to emphasize whatever is important or to express creatively.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I understood the difference.

An example: If something which happened accidentally and I want to take credit for it or I wouldn't like it to be called as an accident, then I will use 'deliberately'. E.g.,

In a game of cricket, I played a shot which by fluke comes off well, but as I wouldn't like it to be called as a fluke then I will say -

> No, that shot didn't come off by fluke but I deliberately played it that way.

I suppose in this example 'on purpose' is not possible or is it?

Comment: Sure it is. I shot it so it would bounce off my forehead on purpose.